# How to set php timezone by offset value in hh:mm, minuts or seconds?

Tags: php, timezone, timezone-offset

My online application gets users timezone offset in `+` or `-` value in minutes. I want to set this value in server.
MySQL / MariaDB accepts timezone values and works perfectly

```
SET time_zone = "+0:15";
```

But php only accepts timezone string like this

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi"); // Works Perfectly
```

And does not set time in offset value

```
date_default_timezone_set("+0:15"); // Error
```

Is there any way to set php time with offset value?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the documentation for the date_default_timezone_set() php function, this seems to be a common issue.

I'm sure there may be alternatives if you choose to use other date functions in php, however, to be able to set the timezone by an offset, you would require a helper function to do this.

I've copied and modified a helper function posted on the php doc page [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php#96551)

```
function setTimezoneByOffset($offset)
{
  $testTimestamp = time();
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $testLocaltime = localtime($testTimestamp,true);
    $testHour = $testLocaltime['tm_hour'];       


$abbrarray = timezone_abbreviations_list();
foreach ($abbrarray as $abbr)
{
    //$abbr."<br>";
  foreach ($abbr as $city)
  {
            date_default_timezone_set($city['timezone_id']);
            $testLocaltime     = localtime($testTimestamp,true);
            $hour                     = $testLocaltime['tm_hour'];       
            $testOffset =  $hour - $testHour;
            if($testOffset == $offset)
            {

                return $city['timezone_id'];
            }
  }
}
return false;
}
```

Where the parameter $offset is a string representation of the offset (ie. `'+0:15'`), which returns the timezone id of the timezone which matches that of your input.

Comment: This approach should be avoided.  All it does is return the first time zone that currently uses a given offset.  It could return drastically different results depending on time of year that the code is run, and ignores all realities of DST and other time zone transitions.

Answer (score 0):

> My online application gets users timezone offset in + or - value in minutes.

This is problematic, because a time zone offset is not the same thing as a time zone.  Consider that one cannot take the *current* offset and assume it is the correct offset to apply for any given date and time.  Many time zones use more than one offset depending on time of year, and many time zones have had changes to their standard time offsets at different points in history.  For more on this, see "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

As an example, you might be using a JavaScript function like `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`.  However, this returns the offset for the `Date` object returned by `new Date()` - which is the *current* date.   For me, in the US Pacific time zone, it will return `480` (UTC-8) when run in the winter during standard time, but `420` (UTC-7) when run in the summer during daylight saving time.

Instead, have your front-end call `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` in JavaScript to return the time zone identifier, which for me returns `"America/Los_Angeles"`.  You can pass that to your back-end and use it with PHP.

As a side note, there are no time zones in the world that use or have ever used UTC+0:15.  The closest to that would have been [UTC+0:20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B00:20) used in the Netherlands from 1 May 1909 to 16 May 1940.  This is already captured in the history of `"Europe/Amsterdam"`.